# How can I create two input tags that have autocomplete function and at the same time the second depends on what's entered in the first input tag?

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a MySQL database called airports which has 2 columns: **name** and **country**.

Obviously **name** has the airport name and **country** the country which it's from. I'm trying to make a kind of airport/flight J2EE web application. I want to create a JSP that has a form that lets the admin create new flights that has the source airport, the source country, the destination airport and the destination country.

I thought about either making an input tag that has an autocomplete function that would help the admin enter the country name and a second input that also has the autocomplete but is only populated by the airports name that are located in the country entered in the first input or I thought about creating 2 select tags in which the second one is only populated by the airports in the country selected above.

I have a Connection class which has a function that gets all the country names from that database table but I don't know what to do after. How can i create those inputs? or those select tags?

I've tried this:

```
<%@page import="com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.JsonArray"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="connectionPackage.ConnectionClass"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
var country= new Array();
$.getJSON("/Jss", function( data ) {
    country = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(country);
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
      data: country
    });
</script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
ConnectionClass class1 = new ConnectionClass();
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list = class1.getCountries();
%>

<form method="post" action="createFlight">
    <div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
          <label for="autocomplete-input">Autocomplete</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried creating a servlet (/Jss) which makes a json object using the arraylist created by the method from the connection class and then I tried calling it in a script in the JSP.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: @brso05 I just added the JSP i tried by it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an auto-complete input field in HTML using a DataList

```
<input list="myData">
<datalist id="myData">
<option value="a" />
<option value="b" />
...
```

And you can dynamically add/remove options from the datalist.

---- edit (How to add & delete) ----

You can add and remove options just like you might from a select

```
//addition
var myOption = ...; // an OPTION element
var dl = document.getElementById("myData").appendChild(myOption);

//removal
var toRemove = document.querySelector("#myData option[value=a]");
```

Comment: How can I add/remove options?

Comment: Thank you but now how can i make the second input depend on what the admin has chosen in the first one?